# Exporting template classes c++

Tags: dll, dllimport, dllexport, .so

**The following is my scenario:** 
I have an executable along with multiple shared libraries(.dll or .so). Both the executable and the shared libraries(.dll or .so) uses a set of common libraries. Since they are common libraries I want to reduce the binary foot print of the shared libraries, in order to reduce the shared library's foot print I am exporting the contents of the common libraries from the executable and importing them in shared libraries(dll or .so).

**Note**: Though size of the foot print is not the only one among multiple reasons, for the time being we can stick with it being major reason.

**Problem**: 
In the common libraries there are some inlined functions and some template classes. When I compile the executable and the shared libraries using performance optimization flags the inlined/ template classes are inlined both in executable and shared libraries. It will create problems if the inline definitions are modified and there are some shared libraries with different set of inline function definitions.

How to solve this problem ?

When I started thinking about this even the STL classes provided by the CRT are template classes. The similar problem exists even in their case. Have they solved this problem? What will happen if they modify the definition of std::vector ? Please help.

Comment: There is no such thing as "template class". C++ has *class templates*. A class template is a template. It isn't a class. You cannot export it from a library. You cannot export an inline function from a library either. You solve this problem by using a modern well-designed programming language.

Comment: Yes I referred to a class template. Thanks for your answer. Can you suggest any other alternatives to solve this problem ? other than changing the programming language.

Comment: Do you know of a single C++ library that solves your problem? Look at the standard library that comes with your compiler. Look at boost. These are the best C++ libraries in existence. Do you want to be better than the very best in the world? That's a very noble desire but don't you think asking strangers on the internet how to do that is a bit naïve?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your quick response. I don't think it was naïve because one of the possible approaches of solving a problem is to check online. When you get stuck on a problem, check online in forums whether some one has/had faced similar problem? and how have they solved it, if they have solved it.

Probably the phrase "can YOU suggest" triggered the wrong idea. I was not trying to force an answer, instead was asking if you knew any alternatives. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

A class template is a mechanism for creating class. But these classed don't get instantiated until you define a particular instance of a class (with a template parameter.)

In your export control file.

```
#ifdef XXXX_BUILD
    #define XXXX_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #define XXXX_EXTERN
#else
    #define XXXX_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #define XXXX_EXTERN extern
#endif
```

where XXXX_BUILD is a symbol defined in your project.

To get your class exported.

```
XXXX_EXTERN template class XXXX_EXPORT YourClass<double>;
```

Where double is the type you want to instantiate the class with.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/168958/how-to-export-an-instantiation-of-a-standard-template-library-stl-clas